# Automatic multiple switch ON when power is applied

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, analog-switch

I have made a switch as shown in the schematics to turn ON/OFF 24 loads. When I apply a pulse on the ON-signal the load gets 24 V and when an OFF-signal pulse is applied the 24 V at the load gets disconnected.

The switch in the schematic works perfectly fine when I test a single switch alone.

Testing procedure: I connect 24 V at VBat+ with respect to GND and find the load LED is OFF. Now, a pulse of 3.3 V peak on the ON-signal turns the the LED (connected as load) ON, and a pulse of 3.3 V peak on the OFF-signal turns the load LED OFF.

Problem: when I connect several such switches to control the power flow from the 24 V source to different loads, the switches get turned ON without even applying the ON-signal/OFF-signal. This happens irrespective of whether the load is connected or not.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

[image: single switch circuit diagram]

Comment: I must say, this is a very neatly hand-drawn circuit!

Comment: is the 10k/LED combination always present? or do you have the output connection really floating with "no load"?

Comment: yes, the load 10k/LED combination is always present there.

Comment: I have a PCB with 7 such switches, 3 of them are working and remaining 4 are not working properly. Is it something related to PCB? Can anybody please help what should i check?